# Is it possible to install MOSS 2007 32 bit with SQL Server 2008 64bit as database server

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a Windows Server 2003 32 bit installed with MOSS 2007 32 bit.

Our database guys have recently bought SQL database Server 2008 64 bit.

I am wondering if it is possible to use new SQL 2008 64 bit machines as database for content of MOSS 2007 32bit.

I appreciate your answer.

Thanks
AK

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Office SharePoint Server 2007 supports SQL Server 2008 x64. However, you must install Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 SP1 or later and Office SharePoint Server 2007 SP1 or later in order to use SQL Server 2008. Office SharePoint Server 2007 also supports SQL Server 2008 R2. Ensure that you have installed Office SharePoint Server 2007 with Service Pack 2 (SP2) or later.

Also, mixing of 32-bit front-ends and 64-bit database servers is supported, but Microsoft doesn't reccomends this scenario because of the perfomance issues with the front-end servers.

I'm using 32-bit front-ends with 2008 x64 machines joined to failover cluster and have no problems.